# Failing for Xdebug to stop on breakpoint when running PHP CLI scripts

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using `vscodium` VSCode distribution and I have placed the following setup in order to be able to debug a PHP script:

```
        {
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run using PHP executable",
            "program": "${file}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
        },
```

Afterwards on Ubuntu 18.04LTS that is the OS that I use for development I installed the `php-xdebug` package:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

And I use the play button in order to launch my script. But for some reason fails to stop into the breakpoint. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: Try 9001 port (in both php.ini and editor). If you have php-pfm running, Xdebug may be connecting there .. as it uses the same 9000 port.

Comment: In order to find out what Xdebug is trying to do, make a remote log as is described at https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs#remote